# Why does a segmentation fault not occur?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am expecting a seg-fault to occurr after the execution of the code below, but it doesn't. Could someone tell me why?

```
int main(){
    float *arr;
    cout << arr[0] << "\n" --> This prints out a ZERO. I am expecting a seg-fault.
        
    cout << arr[1000] << "\n" --> This gives me a seg-fault
        
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering if this due to the "smart" design of the compiler that alleviates the crash. But I can't be sure.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* (which is what happens when you dereference the pointer) doesn't automatically lead to crashes. It might as well seem to work, or set fire to your computer, or summon [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: The computer OS probably allocates memory to the program in pages (usually 4K bytes).  You only get segment faults when you access a page (address) you don't have rights too.  So if `arr[0]` falls with the memory owned by your program (by chance) you will not get a segment fault.

Comment: So there is no clear cut boundary for when it throws a seg-fault, is what you mean?
As above, arr[0] seems to be fine but arr[1000] is not. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. @RichardCritten
So, there is some "padding" before I run into a seg-fautl.

Comment: `float* arr = nullptr;` on some systems will incur a segfault when accessing (technically, it is **undefined behavior**, so props those systems).  Without setting `arr` and subsequently accessing it, the program has **undefined behavior**, and depending on your platform `arr` will have either some *arbitrary* value (often called a *garbage value*), or on some platforms may be marked as uninitialized and reading-before-initializing will cause an *abend* (which is kind of like a segfault, but different).

Comment: Invalid pointer dereferences are not *required* to cause a segmentation violation. The behaviour is formally *undefined* by the C+ standard, which means the standard doesn't place any requirements or constraints on what happens. A segmentation violation occurs *if* your (unix) operating system *detects* your program/process accessing memory it is not allowed to access, and it sends a SIGKILL signal to your process.   The OS won't detect or signal anything if an invalid pointer dereference happens to access some memory the program is allowed to access (e.g. tromping another variable).

Comment: @SanKim It is a mistake in C++ to assume all errors leads to obvious diagnosable errors. A lot of the time it can seem to work or crash randomly, or work up to some point (which can change at any time, for no apparent reason) or work on your system but break on another. If it doesn't crash immediately for you, that is just a possible outcome and cannot be relied upon. Tomorrow it might crash immediately. On my system it might print `42`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux   One problematic form of undefined behaviour is one that never produces an observable symptom on a development machine, but reliably crashes on a paying customer's machine - usually in a way that maximises inconvenience for the customer.   Murphy was an optimist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the pointer `arr` is not initialized, it probably has the value of whatever value that memory address had when it was previously used.

In your case, the code that used that memory address previously probably used that memory address for storing a pointer, i.e. for storing another memory address that points to a valid object. Even if the [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) of that object has expired in the mean time, the operating system will probably not be able to detect this, because the [memory page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) was probably not returned to the operating system. Therefore, as far as the operating system is concerned, that memory page is still readable (and possibly also writable) by the program. This probably explains why dereferencing the uninitialized value of `arr` does not produce a segmentation fault.

The expression `arr[1000]` will attempt to dereference an address that is 4000 bytes apart from the uninitialized value of `arr` (assuming `sizeof(float)==4`). A typical size of a memory page is 4096 bytes. Therefore, assuming that the uninitialized value of `arr` is a memory address that points near the start of a memory page of 4096 bytes, then adding 4000 to that address will not change the memory address sufficiently to make the address point to a different memory page. However, if the uninitialized value of `arr` is a memory address that points somewhere in the middle of a memory page, then adding 4000 to that address will make it point to a different memory page (assuming a memory page size of 4096 bytes). This probably explains why your operating system treats both addresses differently, so that one memory access causes a segmentation fault and the other memory access does not fail.

However, this is all speculation (which is made clear by my frequent use of the word "probably"). There could be another reason why your code does not cause a segmentation fault. In any case, when your program invokes undefined behavior (which it does by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer), you cannot rely on any specific behavior. On some platforms, it may cause a segmentation fault, while on other platforms, the program may work perfectly. Even changing the compiler settings (such as the optimization level) may be enough to change the behavior of the program.

---

> I am wondering if this due to the "smart" design of the compiler that alleviates the crash.

The "smart" thing to do in such a case would be to report some kind of error (i.e. to crash), and not to attempt to alleviate the crash. This is because crashing makes the bug easier to find.

The reason why your program is not crashing immediately is that neither your compiler nor your operating system are detecting the error.

If you want such errors to be detected more reliably, then you may want to consider using a feature offered by some compilers that tries to detect such bugs. For example, both gcc and clang support [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). On those two compilers, all you have to do is compile with the `-fsanitize=address` command-line option. However, this will cause the compiler to add additional checks, which will significantly decrease performance (by a factor of about two) and increase memory usage. Therefore, this should only be done for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks for that indepth answer. Helps alot.

Answer (score 2):

> I am **expecting a seg-fault** to occurr...

Your program has **undefined behavior** since the pointer `arr` is uninitialized and you're dereferencing it implicitly.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

For example, [here](https://onlinegdb.com/YdCkIUaMP) the program doesn't crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/isIBAtSjf7Mz1XLV) it crashes.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>